# Intellij quick documentation is displayed in a separate panel instead of a popup

Tags: intellij-idea

When I click `Option-Q` on an identifier to display the `Quick-Documentation Popup` instead of it showing up in a small dialog directly above the identifier it is showing in a large separate panel to the left.

[image]

This is suboptimal because the content is not where I wanted to look for it and because the new panel overlays the entire right side of the editor panel (and its contents).

Is there a `Preferences` setting for getting this to be a `popup` again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! There's a configuration menu that can be accessed by ***Right clicking on the top bar of the tool window***. The first option `Open as Popup` is the one I wanted:

[image]